# Reuse single reference schema with multiple validation restrictions

Tags: c#, njsonschema

I have one schema which I want to use for 2 properties:

```
{
        
        "title": "testschema",
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "required": [
          "prop2"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "prop1": {
            "type": "object",
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/commonSchema"
          },
          "prop2": {
            "type": "object",
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/commonSchema"
          }
        }
      }
```

Now I want that prop2 should be validated for the requiredproperties mentioned in common schema, but prop1 should not. Since this ref schema is shared, I cannot keep the requiredproperties in the commonschema.
Is there a way wherein I can add these validations on a ref schema without having them added in it directly?

Also note that I'm dynamically creating this schema in c# so not sure how the conditional required conditions are to be programmed in the schema.Is there a way to sate this condition in commonschema that if its parent schema title=="prop2" then apply the required fields validation

Comment: @ricosuter - can you please help,is this not possible currently?

Comment: @Rico Suter - can you please help,is this not possible currently?